3500 Watt Inverter current runaway
I have a 3500 watt inverter connected to a 400AH LiFePo4 battery (with 200A BMS) using #2 wire.
I connect my RV A/C to this inverter. It will start the A/C and it blows cold air. Initially the DC Current is around 90 Amps, but the DC current starts increasing until the BMS trips and shuts down the inverter.  I suspect it is a bad inverter but want to verify with others in case I missed something in my design.

in case I missed something in my design ... your design is unknown

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Is it likely my inverter is faulty and that is why the current keeps increasing until the BMS trips?

Are you seeing increased current in the inverter output?

I had not thought of that. Thank you for that insight.  I will have to check that later today and see if the output is increasing as well.


This is the power drawn by the water heat pump I use for heating. It starts around 5kW, then increases to 6kW as water temperature in the heating circuit rises.
\$ \Delta T \$ is the temperature difference between the hot and cold side of the heat pump. When \$ \Delta T \$ increases, all heat pumps lose COP (Coefficient of Performance) which is the ratio between thermal power output and electrical power input. So when when \$ \Delta T \$ increases, if thermal output power is constant then electrical power used increases, and if electrical power remains constant then output thermal power drops.
For air conditioning we use EER (Energy Efficiency ratio) instead of COP. Basically all the electrical power used by the heat pump ends up on the hot side, so when you use it as heating it is beneficial, but when you use it as cooling it is waste. Thus COP is (Thermal power at the hot side)/(electrical power) and EER is (Thermal power at the cold side)/(electrical power)... and COP = EER+1.
Anyway. Your aircon is a heat pump too. So when you turn it on, temperature on the cold side (inside the room) should be pretty much the same as temperature on the hot side (outside air). With \$ \Delta T = 0 \$ its EER will be very high so it will consume little electrical power to pump its rated thermal power. However after a while, hopefully the inside of the RV is now much cooler than outside, which means higher \$ \Delta T \$, lower EER, and more electrical power is required.
Basically it requires more power to pump heat across a larger temperature difference.
So you should use a wattmeter to measure this. This power increase is normal, there is nothing you can do about it besides using an inverter heat pump with variable power, and playing with the settings.
Then you should check input current and voltage, thus DC input power at the inverter. If it tracks output power, with 10-20% wasted due to the inverter not being 100% efficient, then... normal. If you see inverter input power rise a lot faster than output power, after accounting for 80-90% efficiency, then your inverter loses efficiency when running hot, which could be a problem.
Then check voltage drop in the wires. The inverter must output the power required by the A/C, so if there is significant voltage drop in the wires, voltage at the inverter is lower, which means it must draw even more current... causing even more voltage drop in the wires... which means more current... so in a logical but somewhat counter-intuitive way, if your wires are too thin, the inverter will use more current! (and the wires will heat even more).
This voltage drop issue doesn't just apply to wires, but to anything with resistance, including battery, BMS, etc.
